# GoCD Custom Command

Tags: go-cd

I am trying to run a very simple custom command "echo helloworld" in GoCD as per the [Getting Started Guide Part 2](https://www.gocd.org/getting-started/part-2/) however, the job does not finish with the Console saying `Waiting for console logs` and raw output saying `Console log for this job is unavailable as it may have been purged by Go or deleted externally.`

[image]

My job looks like the following which was taken from typing "echo" in the Lookup Command (which is different to the Getting Started example which I tried first with the same result)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the screenshot, the problem seems to be that no agent is assigned to the task. For an agent to be assigned, it must satisfy all of these conditions:

- An agent must be running, and connected to the server
- The agent must be enabled on the "Agents" page
- If you use environments, the job and the agent need to be in the same environment
- The agent needs to have all of the resources assigned that are configured in the job

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

The Pipelines have to be in the same Environment to work.